# Are there any easy way to select in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I get the languageCode like below. Are there any easy way to get languageCode?

```
var activeLanguages = GetAllActiveLanguages().Where(e => e.Id == Id).ToList();

foreach (var l in activeLanguages)

{

    language = l.LanguageCode;

}
```

Comment: googling "select linq" would probably have gotten you an answer. You may be interested in [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you expect exactly one match, use [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118.aspx)

```
language = GetAllActiveLanguages().Single(e => e.Id == Id).LanguageCode;
```

Comment: Upvoted. _Maybe_ without the `var` if the variable is declared elsewhere (could also be a field) which is not clear from the question. ***Edit:*** Don't you miss the `.LanguageCode`?

Answer (score 3):

Of course, just put

```
.Select(e => e.LanguageCode)
```

into your query:

```
var activeLanguages =
  GetAllActiveLanguages()
  .Where(e => e.Id == Id)
  .Select(e => e.LanguageCode)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: That would get an IEnumerable, where I guess they want one single code.

Comment: Then they wouldn't use `ToList` but `Single` or `First`. And no `foreach` either.

Answer (score 2):

Ussing the `.Select(expression)` method, you will get a result that it contains, for sample, selecting a single property, instead you specify you want one item, you will get a `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is the type of the property you have selected.

For `public string LanguageCode { get; set; }`:

```
List<string> activeLanguages = GetAllActiveLanguages()
                               .Where(e => e.Id == Id)
                               .Select(x => x.LanguageCode)
                               .ToList();
```

You also can get only the first one:

```
string firstActiveLanguages = GetAllActiveLanguages()
                               .Where(e => e.Id == Id)
                               .Select(x => x.LanguageCode)
                               .FirstOrDefault();
```

You also can get the `Last` item:

```
string firstActiveLanguages = GetAllActiveLanguages()
                               .Where(e => e.Id == Id)
                               .Select(x => x.LanguageCode)
                               .LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: He might want the LastOrDefault language code. That's what the foreach would achieve.

Comment: First and Last (and variants) return one element. You can't use Select after.